# how does bitvise port forwarding work?

Tags: ssh, port, forwarding, tunneling

One of our DBs is behind firewall. 
I could not use it through its natural port `1521`. 
I also know the same machine is accessible through the SSH port ( 22)

My friend showed me BitVise SSH Client, so that by tunneling through the SSH port , I accessed the invulnerable 1521 port and used my favorite Sql Developer tool.

My question is , how do you tunnel some data through the SSH port, what is the mechanics ? 
I.e. is there some SSH command like, "after successful login pass the data as is to the given port"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a SSH client to connect to the Bitvise SSH server.  Bitvise also has a client product called Bitvise Tunnelier that you can configure to use port forwarding.  You would configure Tunnelier to listen for and forward a specific port (the SQL connection in your case).  Then, you would configure your SQL Dev Tool to connect to localhost: and connect.

More information about Bitvise and port forwarding:
https://www.bitvise.com/port-forwarding

This link will show you how to use Port Forwarding with Remote Desktop, but you can adapt it to use it for SQL, etc:
https://www.bitvise.com/remote-desktop